# SQL Case Statements with Multiple Max Conditions

Tags: sql, powerbi

I currently am working with two conditions that I would like to combine into one, but ran into some trouble.  I have a dataset that includes quantity and date. I have created a date flag in the form of a case statement that flags whether it is the last day of the week, and gives it a "Y" or "N".  The end result that I need is what that last DATE of the week.
[My end result/goal is Column D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBkWU.jpg)

Here is my current source code:

```
select
   pos.quantity_on_hand,
   d.cal_date,
   case
      when date_key in( Select max(date_key) from edw.D_dates group by fiscal_year_nbr, fiscal_week_nbr)
      then 'Y'
      else 'N'
   end Week_end_flag
from
   edw.f_pos_daily pos,
   edw.d_dates d,
where
   pos.pos_date_key = d.date_key
```

I then create another custom column in PowerBI Desktop that looks like this:
This is what I used for my column calculation:

```
Last Inventory Date = RETURN(CALCULATE(MAXX(Inventory, Inventory[Cal_date]), filter ('D_Dates', 'D_Dates'[Week_end_flag]="Y")).
```

I tried to combine them into one, with something like this, but have failed:

```
case
   when date_key in( Select max(date_key) from edw.D_dates group by fiscal_year_nbr, fiscal_week_nbr)
   then MAX (cal_date) from edw.D_Dates where cal_date< current_date AS 'yyyy-mm-dd'
   else 'N'
end Week_End_flag
```

Comment: In which part you are facing issue, SQL or Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Use the select command inside the then clause

change this line:

```
then MAX (cal_date) from edw.D_Dates where cal_date< current_date AS 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

to:

```
then (SELECT MAX (cal_date) from edw.D_Dates where cal_date< current_date AS 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

complete code:

```
select
   pos.quantity_on_hand,
   d.cal_date,
   case
      when date_key in( Select max(date_key) from edw.D_dates group by fiscal_year_nbr, fiscal_week_nbr)
      then (SELECT MAX (cal_date) from edw.D_Dates where cal_date< current_date AS 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      else 'N'
   end Week_end_flag
from
   edw.f_pos_daily pos,
   edw.d_dates d,
where
   pos.pos_date_key = d.date_key
```